# char to cell MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell

If I have this element type "char":

```
A=['abc';'dei';'fgh'];
```

And I want to obtain something like:

```
B=somefuntion(A)
```

And obtain something like this:

```
B={'abs';'dei';'fgh'}
```

I tried this function called [char2cell](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24915-char2cell), but the result was this:

```
B = 'adfbegcih';
```

I really appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mat2cell`:

```
 F=mat2cell(A,ones(size(A,1),1),size(A,2))
```

The code splits every row into one cell(`ones(size(A,1),1)`) and keeps the columns together (`size(A,2)`)